Proof That There is a Sequence Converging to $f'(c)$
Suppose $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ is differentiable and $c\in{[a,b]}$. Prove that there exists a sequence $\{x_n\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ such that ${\forall{n}\in\mathbb{N}}, x_n\neq{c}, \lim_{n\to\infty}{x_n}=c$, and $\lim_{n\to\infty}{f'(x_n)}=f'(c)$.
My Attempt: Define $\{y_n\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ such that $\forall{n}\in\mathbb{N}$, $y_n\neq{f'(c)}$, and $\lim_{n\to\infty}{y_n}=f'(c)$. Also suppose that $\forall{n}\in\mathbb{N}$, either $f'(c)<y_n<f'(b)$ or $f'(c)>y_n>f'(b)$ (note that this is assuming $f'(c)\neq{f'(b)}$, if $f'(c)=f'(b)$ I assume we might be able to do some  proof for that specific case). Now by Darboux's theorem, for each $y_n$ we can find an $x_n\in(c,b)$ such that $f'(x_n)=y_n$. This gives, $\lim_{n\to\infty}{f'(x_n)}=\lim_{n\to\infty}{y_n}=f'(c)$. I have two of the three conditions for $\{x_n\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$  satisfied, but I am unsure on how to prove that $lim_{n\to\infty}{x_n}=c$ or if such a statement is true at all given the conditions.
